# Updating 33 Million Rows - Optimization

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am updating a `varchar` column in a table which has 33 million rows. This is what I have come up with, the script is taking around 50 minutes on my development machine. Is there any way I can increase the performance?

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON

DECLARE @NewPrefix VARCHAR(255)
        ,@OldPrefix VARCHAR(255)
        ,@Rowcount BIGINT = 1
        ,@BatchSize INT = 100000
        ,@ModBy VARCHAR(50)
        ,@ModStation VARCHAR(50)
        ,@UpdatedCount BIGINT = 0;

SET @ModBy = 'User1'
SET @ModStation = 'abc001'

SET @OldPrefix = 'http://OldPrefix/'
SET @NewPrefix = 'http://NewPrefix/'

WHILE (@Rowcount > 0)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    UPDATE TOP (@BatchSize) tblFiles
    SET FileLocation = REPLACE(FileLocation, @OldPrefix, @NewPrefix),
        ModDate = GETDATE(), 
        ModBy = @ModBy,
        ModStation = @ModStation
    WHERE ModStation <> @ModStation
      AND FileLocation IS NOT NULL

    SET @Rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT;
    SET @UpdatedCount = @UpdatedCount + @Rowcount

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END

SELECT @UpdatedCount AS 'Records Updated.'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an index on `(ModStation)` (or `(ModStation, FileLocation)` ) in your table? That would at least speed up the "discovery" of the rows to be updated

Comment: How many of the rows that match `WHERE ModStation <> @ModStation
      AND FileLocation IS NOT NULL` contain the prefix that you are replacing? All of them? If not what proportion?

Comment: 26 million are matched with the condition FileLocation IS NOT NULL

Comment: @marc_s - No, I don't have any indexes on those tables.

Answer (score 0):

When `@ModStation` is a constant, I would suggested a filtered index and not use a variable for `ModStation <> @ModStation` but rather, `ModStation <> 'abc001'`

At the beginning of your script:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_tblFiles_Temp
ON tblFiles
(
    YourPrimaryKey
)
WHERE ModStation <> 'abc001'
      AND FileLocation IS NOT NULL
```

And drop the index, at the end of your script.

If mod station is a variable the you could still create a filter index for file location.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_tblFiles_Temp
ON tblFiles
(
    ModStation 
)
WHERE FileLocation IS NOT NULL
```

---

If you are updating foreign key columns, you could choose to drop/disable the foreign key constraints in the beginning of your script, and recreating/enabling them at the end of your script.

---

Also consider removing the `while` when you are using the indexes or increasing the batch size (1.000.000 may be faster, depending on the hardware, size of the columns)

---

You can also specify `WITH (TABLOCK)` on your update to lock the complete table. (Instead of having lock escalation)
Example

```
UPDATE TOP (@BatchSize) tblFiles
WITH (TABLOCK) -- Forcing a table lock
SET FileLocation = REPLACE(FileLocation, @OldPrefix, @NewPrefix),
    ModDate = GETDATE(), 
    ModBy = @ModBy,
    ModStation = @ModStation
WHERE ModStation <> @ModStation
      AND FileLocation IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The first point of performance loss in any query writing datas is the speed of writing into the transaction log.
Be sure that the transaction log has been well dimensionned, like every DBA should do by planning the capacity of the file for the transaction log.
Any growth operation of the transaction log will consume time...

Answer (score 0):

Yes increase your computer performance such as memory and processor